# Delphi "Invalid class type case" issue

Tags: json, delphi

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, DBXJSON, System.JSON;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
 const Url = 'url';


function JSONArrayCovertCnt(usJSON: string): integer;
var
  JSONPair : TJSONPair;
  JSONArray : TJSONArray;

begin
  usJson := StringReplace(usJSON,'\"','"',[rfReplaceAll]);
  JSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(usJSON) as TJSONArray;

  Result := JSONArray.Count;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  stream: TStringStream;                                                                                          idHttpObj: TIdHTTP;
  JSONValue : TJSONvalue;
  i : integer;
  JSONArray  : TJSONArray;
  result : integer;

begin
  stream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8); //

  idHttpObj := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  idHttpObj.Get(Url, stream);
  idHttpObj.Free;

  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(stream.DataString);
  memo1.Clear;

  for i := 0 to 3 do
  begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('year: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('data['+i.ToString+'].year') + 'year');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('hshld: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('data['+i.ToString+'].hshld') + 'hshld');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('popltn: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('data['+i.ToString+'].popltn_sm') + '명');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('popltn_male: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('data['+i.ToString+'].popltn_male') + '명');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('popltn_female: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('data['+i.ToString+'].popltn_female') + '명');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('hshld_avrgpopltn: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('data['+i.ToString+'].hshld_avrgpopltn') + '명');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('────────────────────────────────────');

  end;


  Memo1.Lines.Add('resultCode: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('resultCode'));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('resultMsg: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('resultMsg'));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('numOfRows : ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('numOfRows'));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('resultCode: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('resultCode'));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('totalcount: ' + JSONValue.GetValue<string>('totalCount'));

  result := JSONArrayCovertCnt(stream.DataString);
  edit1.Text := IntToStr(result);

  stream.Free;
end;

end.
```

```json
{
"data":
    [
        {
        "popltn_female":134301,
        "year":"2012",
        "hshld_avrgpopltn":2.65,
        "hshld":102031,
        "popltn_sm":270460,
        "popltn_male":136159
        }
    ]

"pageNo":1,
"currentCount":9,
"resultCode":0,
"totalCount":9,
"numOfRows":10,
"resultMsg":"정상"
}
```

I want to calculate how many data array values are in a JSONValue.

I tried to find, input, and apply the function code through Google search, but I get an error.

> Invalid class type cast

How can we solve this problem?

I asked a question using a translator because I am a Korean who is not good at English at all.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't good at asking questions
I will add JSON contents to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Please include the **complete, exact error message*, which in Delphi will tell you exactly what line is causing the problem. Click on the error in the message window to select it, right-click it, and copy the message, which you can then paste directly into your question.

Comment: Does the program run normally?
When you click on button 1,
result := JSONArrayCovertCnt(stream.DataString);
There is an error in syntax.

Comment: @상프로TV I don't see any syntax error in this code. If anything, the only thing I do see wrong is using `DBXJSON` and `System.JSON`, that is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON data you have shown represents an *object* (which is denoted by `{ }`), not an *array* (which is denoted by `[ ]`), so `ParseJSONValue()` will return a `TJSONValue` pointing at a `TJSONObject`, not a `TJSONArray`. As such, the `as` typecast to `TJSONArray` will fail with a runtime error.  The `data` field inside the JSON object is an array.

---

On a side note, there are other problems with your code:

- your use of `StringReplace()` is completely unnecessary and should be removed. Your JSON doesn't contain any `'\'` characters, but even if it did, removing *anything* from the JSON is wrong. You need to parse it exactly as it was received.
- all of your `Create`/`Free` pairs need to be protected with `try`/`finally`.
- you are leaking both `TJSONValue` objects that `ParseJSONValue()` returns.
- you don't need the `TStringStream` at all, as `TIdHTTP.Get()`has an overload that returns a `String`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.

I understand the deletion, but I don't know how to add and modify the second one.
--------------------
```delphi
begin
 //[-]usJson := StringReplace(usJSON,'\"','"',[rfReplaceAll]);
end;
```

Comment: @상프로TV "*I don't know how to add and modify the second one*" - I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: The solution was obtained from the added answers. Thank you.

Comment: " removing anything from the JSON is wrong. You need to parse it exactly as it was received." - well, depending on what other system produced that JSON (TSQL comes to mind) there are situations where you may need to preprocess/clean it up